# Custom number formatter with hyperlink link

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have achieved most of what is required but stuck up with a small issue.

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jqGrid 4.4.0. It has a Rate column that acts as link to open a modal box with break up details. The issue is that the values in Rate column are purely numbers and I have used a custom template to set the formatting to its values but due to link (custom formatter) the formatting goes off.

HTML Code:

```
<table id="tbCmpContents">
    <tr><td/></tr>
</table>
<div id="divCmpContentsPager"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
var mydata = [
    {Id: "2", Element: "Salt",  Qty: "10.00", Rate: "21200.00", Cost: "200.00"},
    {Id: "3", Element: "Sugar", Qty: "20.00", Rate: "32500.00", Cost: "600.00"}
],
viewNumTemplate = {
    align: 'right',
    classes: 'numberPadding',
    formatter: 'number',
    formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: "", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00' },
    sortable: false,
    width: 100
},
getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
    for (var i = 0, l = cm.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
            return i; // return the index
        }
    }
    return -1;
},
getTextFromCell = function (cellNode) {
    var cellValue;
    //check for all INPUT types
    if (cellNode.childNodes[0].nodeName == "INPUT") {
        //special case for handling checkbox
        if (cellNode.childNodes[0].type == "checkbox") {
            cellValue = cellNode.childNodes[0].checked.toString();
        }
        else {
            //catch-all for all other inputs - text/integer/amount etc
            cellValue = cellNode.childNodes[0].value;
        }
    }
    //check for dropdown list
    else if (cellNode.childNodes[0].nodeName == "SELECT") {
        var newCell = $("select option:selected", cellNode);
        cellValue = newCell[0].value;
    }
    else {
        cellValue = cellNode.textContent || cellNode.innerText;
    }
    return cellValue;
},
calculateTotal = function (grid) {
    var totalRate = 0.00;

    i = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'Rate');
    $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", grid[0]).each(function () {
        totalRate += Number(getTextFromCell(this).replace(",", ""));
    })

    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Rate: totalRate.toFixed(2) }, false );
};

function OpenInModal(id) {
    //Open a modal window to render the break-up of rate for an element.
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var oGrid = $('#tbCmpContents');

    oGrid.jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Element', 'Qty', 'Rate', 'Cost'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, key: true },
            { name: 'Element', index: 'Element', width: 120, sortable: true },
            { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 100, formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sortable: false },
            { name: 'Rate', index: 'Rate', width: 100, template: viewNumTemplate, 
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return '<a href="javascript:OpenInModal(\'' + rowObject[0] + '\')">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
                }
            },
            { name: 'Cost', index: 'Cost', width: 100, formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sortable: false }
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortname: 'Element',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        caption: 'Compound Contents',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        footerrow: true,
        loadonce: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            calculateTotal($(this));
            $("#tbCmpContents tr:last").addClass('ireg-jqgrid-lastrow');
            $("tr.footrow td").addClass('ireg-jqgrid-lastrow').addClass('ireg-jqgrid-footer');
        }
    });
});
```

One way out is that I can write a function to format number with required formatting (such as thousand separator, decimal place, etc.) and apply it to cellvalue in custom formatter function but I was wondering if there is any way in jqGrid with which I can achieve the same.

I request all the jqGrid expert to suggest. Thank you all in advance.

Sample code: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eD9tH/)

Comment: I read your question 3 times and I'm a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish. You want a number formatted with commas, decimal place, but still with acting as a hyperlink?

Comment: @Mark, apologies for not putting things very clearly. The value in rate column is calculated based on certain values in DB. When user clicks on any value (number) in the rate column, I show the break-up of the same in a modal window. The issue is that if I convert Rate column into hyperlink, I loose the number formatting, which I don't want. Hence, I need to know if there any built-in way to achieve hyperlink functionality with number formatting. The other way I know of is to create a custom function that will return the formatted string for the given number. Hope this helps in understanding.